# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of null

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate

My SVG animation works fine on [codepen](https://codepen.io/hijulia/pen/QMMVNj)

But when I add it to [my page](http://julia-chen.com/sf-illustrations/) it doesn't work anymore. I keep getting this message in console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of null

at animatePath (sf.js:4)

at sf.js:21

`4   var length = path.getTotalLength();
21   animatePath('#bigs', 'stroke-dashoffset 0.6s ease-in-out');`

Comment: once you move your code `path` is `null`, so where is `path` being defined?

Comment: It appears that whatever you are passing to that function for a pathName is not being found on the page. make sure you include the . if it is a class or a # if it is an ID

Comment: it looks like there is no element on the page with the ID 'bigs'

Comment: I have a path with the ID 'bigs' in my html file

`<path id="bigs" class="st0" d="M53,124.6c0,0-16.3,13.3-7.4,34s34,14.8,48.8,5.9s25.9-31.8,25.2-40c-0.7-8.1-14.1-15.5-30.3-2.2
  s-28.1,25.2-22.2,57.7s18.5,30.3,10.4,56.2s-37,29.6-48.8,25.2S4.9,245.3,7.9,226s22.2-23.7,22.2-23.7"/>
`

Comment: your page "my page" contains invalid markup. You should fix that and see if it makes any difference. If you want any more help please add a [mcve] to the question ensuring it actually demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the SVG has loaded and the DOM is ready before you can get a reference to the path.  Your Javascript is running too soon, so the

```
var path = document.querySelector(pathname);
```

is returning null.

This doesn't affect the codepen because it is running the Javascript after the load.

To fix this, wrap your `animatePath()` calls in something like the following:

```
window.onload = function() {
  animatePath('#bigs', 'stroke-dashoffset 0.6s ease-in-out');
  animatePath('#a1', 'stroke-dashoffset 0.5s 0.5s ease-in-out');
  ...
}
```